# splitting string having date and time in actionscript

Tags: actionscript

I have two values coming in together in Duration field(String type) as `dd-Mon-yyyy HH24:MI:SS`. Now I have to split it into two separate fields such that only `dd-Mon-yyyy` form `dd-Mon-yyyy HH24:MI:SS` goes in one TextBox(i.e.Duration textbox) and `HH24:MI:SS` goes into another TextBox(i.e.Time textbox)

Answer (score 0):

Do you always have a space between the two values?

```
function splitMyString(str:String):Array
{
    return split(" ");
}
```

This'll return an array where `array[0]` is the first half and `array[1]` is the second half. But ONLY if you have a space character between both values.